# Errors with facebook implementation

Tags: php, same-origin-policy

I read a lot of topics, I tried to add on my php page the next:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.facebook.com');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

But I always have a lot of errors in chrome console. Is it possible to fix them?

Webpage: https://cinqueterre.a-turist.com/how_to_arrive.php

1. Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin * from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com". The frame being accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
2. Refused to display 'https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/drt/si?p=CAE&ut=AFAKxlQAAAAAU-4O…srx1W_wnAqGzyR2y1sYxYQgrUnv95hoZAyZZAhfN3j4sr_XKepNlwpDEVqs0XrKasSfc&dpt=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

One more question, is it possible to offer money revenue for the help here? Sometimes I would like to pay someone to get help or suggestions, but don't know where to search for it.

Comment: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` allowes code originated from another sources access your data, not the other way around.

Comment: I don't understand well this part, so in this case everyone get error when implement facebook comments / google ads?